# Bootstrap Carousel Text Fade

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to prevent the caption of a bootstrap carousel from sliding with the background image, and instead, on 'slide' fade out, and on 'slid' the new caption fade in?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using the CSS-only solution:

```
.item.next .carousel-caption {
    opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-caption {
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

It does rely on CSS3 transitions and does therefore not work in older browsers (for IE that means atleast version 10) but it's time to code for the future!

Comment: Love the pure CSS solution. Remember to take account of `.item.prev` as well. To use in conjunction with animate.css library, use `display:none` instead of `opacity:0`;

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to attach functions to the 'slid' and 'slide' events...

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide',function(){
  $('.carousel-caption').fadeOut(300);
})
$('#myCarousel').on('slid',function(){
  $('.carousel-caption').fadeIn(600);
})
```

Demo with animation: http://bootply.com/69740

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3 it would be

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel',function(){
$('.carousel-caption').fadeOut(300);
})
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel',function(){
 $('.carousel-caption').fadeIn(600);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works... It still sort of slides with the carousel, but you do get the fadeOut and fadeIn affect.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide',function(){
    $('#myCarousel .active .carousel-caption').fadeOut();
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slid',function(){
    $('#myCarousel .active .carousel-caption').fadeIn();
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/sYzXh/1/) demo.